# Question about the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$ diverges?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\cdot\frac1n\sim\frac1{\mathrm e}\cdot\frac1n$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice for any positive integer $n$, $\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$, we have

$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n+1}\bigg/\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} > \frac{1}{e(n+1)}$$

This implies
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{e(n+1)} \sim O\left(\frac{\log N}{e}\right)$$
which diverges as $N \to \infty$.