# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^k/(k+1)^{k+1}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to see if the below series converges or diverges:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}.$$
The root test gives a value of one hence it is inconclusive. The other usual tests didn't work or didn't have any obvious candidates (e.g. root test, limit comparison test). I am stuck on what to try next. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about the convergence of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641369/question-about-the-convergence-of-a-series) Or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790304 Or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073401 (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%5Ek%7D%7B(k%2B1)%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%7D%24&p=1))

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes it does. I was sure someone must have asked it before, but I couldn't find it no matter what I searched. May I ask, how do you find duplicates? Especially for these kind of questions, the google search is not very helpful.